# Card View in Android not shownig shadow and corners

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-cardview

Shadow in CardView not working. When i Put anything in Card View, corners in CardView gone disappear too. In Preview tools in Android Studio look like very good but for all my devices not look lilke similar.
I working on Android 9.0. It is problem with this version?

My version of material design
implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0")

[Preview in Android Studio tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4Yo4.png)

[What showing on my tablet screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7NpY.png)

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"

        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative_image_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.75"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/itemImage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/emaenu_game"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/picture"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view10"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@color/main_emenu"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.25"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/relative_image_view" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minHeight="0dp"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:paddingEnd="15dp"
                android:text="Water Flow"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/black_emenu"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view10"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view10"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/relative_image_view" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add this to cardView

```
app:cardElevation="3dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
```

Please remove this 2 line

```
app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

And CardView will be Parent layout not ConstraintLayout so Please remove upper ConstraintLayout.

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/AnyColor">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

I am sure after this it will show shadow and corner radius.

Comment: It working but not in my project . Can It  be problem with theme or something like that ?

Comment: @PawełKrzyściak The reason is that you have used some attributes that block the main property of the material card view. you have removed the upper constraint layout? if yes then remove all the background color and just put corner radius and cardElevation. and Height and width and then it has to work.

Comment: thanks, I found solution for me .. i forgot delete this line in manifest
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"